# I am trying to Process a json file but while checking from JsonLint I get error Expecting 'EOF', got ','

Tags: json, jsonlint

Error: Parse error on line 12:
..."disliked": "true"}, {   "liked": "true"
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', got ','

Json:

{
    "liked": "true",
    "user_id": "101",
    "video_end_type": "3",
    "minutes_played": "3",
    "video_id": "101",
    "geo_cd": "AP",
    "channel_id": "11",
    "creator_id": "101",
    "timestamp": "07/05/2019 01:36:35",
    "disliked": "true"
}, {
    "liked": "true",
    "user_id": "102",
    "video_end_type": "null",
    "minutes_played": "4",
    "video_id": "102",
    "geo_cd": "AP",
    "channel_id": "12",
    "creator_id": "102",
    "timestamp": "15/04/2019 17:04:00",
    "disliked": "true"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid JSON structure. There are two root elements and based on your JSON structure it appears that this is supposed to be a collection. Wrap your JSON structure in [] to make it a collection.

```
[
   {
      "liked":"true",
      "user_id":"101",
      "video_end_type":"3",
      "minutes_played":"3",
      "video_id":"101",
      "geo_cd":"AP",
      "channel_id":"11",
      "creator_id":"101",
      "timestamp":"07/05/2019 01:36:35",
      "disliked":"true"
   },
   {
      "liked":"true",
      "user_id":"102",
      "video_end_type":"null",
      "minutes_played":"4",
      "video_id":"102",
      "geo_cd":"AP",
      "channel_id":"12",
      "creator_id":"102",
      "timestamp":"15/04/2019 17:04:00",
      "disliked":"true"
   }
]
```